# How to add files to a github wiki page?

Tags: git, github, wiki

I was trying to edit a wiki file and add more files to it. At some point I need to upload a file to the wiki. What I need to add should be similar to below.

> [somename.pdf]
> (Files/Theses/somename.pdf)

Also shown in below screenshot:

[image]

**My problem is that, I couldn't find the Files/Theses directory in the repository to upload a new PDF file.** It is my first time working with a wiki page. I did everything, I searched keywords in the repository but there is no folder containing these files or folder. Do you guys know where is should be?
This is a list of wikis.
[image]

and this is our repository:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a relatively new feature but GitHub supports (in page edit mode) attaching a file and inserting a link within the page via simple drag and drop or copy/paste. See [Upload images to Wiki pages](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-14-upload-images-to-wiki-pages/):

> You can now upload images to Wiki pages. Drag and drop, select or paste the file.